# Game packaging package results: error: unknown error in unreal engine 4

Tags: windows, unreal-engine4

I'm not packing a game on Unreal Engine 4 Error code 6 Error unknown error help me this is the first project so I don't know how to fix it

> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): Writing manifest to
>
> C:\Users\etuhv\OneDrive\Документы\Unreal
> Projects\Kiwis_Toy_Store\Intermediate\Build\Manifest.xml
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): Building Kiwis_Toy_Store...
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): Using Visual Studio 2019
> 14.29.30148 toolchain (C:\Program
>
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133) and Windows
>
> 10.0.19041.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): [Upgrade]
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): [Upgrade] Using
> backward-compatible build settings. The
>
> latest version of UE4 sets the following values by default, which may
> require code changes:
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): [Upgrade]
> bLegacyPublicIncludePaths = false => Omits
>
> subfolders from public include paths to reduce compiler command line
> length. (Previously: true).
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): [Upgrade]
> ShadowVariableWarningLevel = WarningLevel.Error
>
> => Treats shadowed variable warnings as errors. (Previously: WarningLevel.Warning).
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): [Upgrade] PCHUsage =
> PCHUsageMode.UseExplicitOrSharedPCHs
>
> => Set in build.cs files to enables IWYU-style PCH model. See https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-
>
> US/Programming/BuildTools/UnrealBuildTool/IWYU/index.html .
> (Previously:
>
> PCHUsageMode.UseSharedPCHs).
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): [Upgrade] Suppress this
> message by setting
>
> 'DefaultBuildSettings = BuildSettingsVersion.V2;' in
> Kiwis_Toy_Store.Target.cs, and explicitly  overriding settings that
> differ from the new defaults.
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): [Upgrade]
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): Building 4 actions with 4
> processes...
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): [1/4] SharedPCH.Core.cpp
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): c1xx: fatal error C1083: ��
> 㤠���� ������ 䠩�
>
> �஬������ ��� ���������:
> C:\Users\etuhv\OneDrive\�"�?��?�?��?�'�<\Unreal
>
> Projects\Kiwis_Toy_Store\Intermediate\Build\Win64\Kiwis_Toy_Store\Shipping\Core\SharedPCH.Core.h.pch
>
> : No such file or directory,
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): Took 4,4673882s to run
> UnrealBuildTool.exe, ExitCode=6
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): UnrealBuildTool failed. See
> log for more details.
>
> (C:\Users\etuhv\AppData\Roaming\Unreal
>
> Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\C+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_4.27\UBT-Kiwis_Toy_Store-Win64-
>
> Shipping.txt)
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): AutomationTool exiting with
> ExitCode=6 (6)
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): BUILD FAILED
>
> PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error

I tried to fix it, but it didn't work out, I searched all over Google and YouTube, but I didn't find a solution to the error